# How to get current global date time(not mobile date time) in react native?

Tags: react-native, date, datetime, momentjs

I want the current date time. currently, I am using moment but it takes device date time.
How can I achieve this in react native?

Comment: What is a "global date time"?

Comment: I want current date time not the mobile's date time  @SalmanA

Comment: Do you mean UTC time (the time with +00:00 offset) ? You can use `moment.utc()` to get this. See docs [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).